# Mapeando uma enumeração

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Eu tenho um problema com o hibernate:
Quando eu tento dar *wakeup* no server, ele me dá a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class.

Dizendo que estou tentando usar estas anotações em uma classe não mapeada, mas essa classe em questão é uma enumeração.

```
@OneToMany
private List<Generos> generos;
```

Qual anotação devo usar para mapear esta enumeração e resolver o problema?

OBS: Já tentei usar a anotação `@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)` no método getter, como sugeria o site que eu procurei, mas não resolveu meu problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos supor que o que você queira mapear é que os gêneros são de alimentos. Ou seja, uma entidade `Alimento` contém um `List<Generos>`.

Tente fazer algo assim:

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Generos.class)
@CollectionTable(name = "tb_alimentos_generos", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "alimento_id"))
@Column(name = "genero_id", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
private Set<Generos> generos;
```

Explicação:

Você deve usar `@OneToMany` para relacionar entidades. Ocorre que o `enum` não é uma entidade. Para listas de `String`s, números, datas, `enum`s e `@Embedded`s, no JPA 2 em diante há a anotação `@CollectionTable`.

A anotação `@CollectionTable` especifica que a tabela onde os gêneros de cada alimento vão ser guardados será a `tb_alimentos_genero`. A chave estrangeira desta tabela para a tabela modelada na entidade envolvente será modelado pela coluna `alimento_id`.

Nesta tabelinha, a coluna `genero_id` (de acordo com a anotação `@Column`) conterá o valor ordinal do gênero armazenado na tupla (de acordo com o `@Enumerated(Enumtype.ORDINAL)`).

Assim sendo, na tabela `tb_alimentos_genero` há duas colunas: `alimento_id` que é chave estrangeira e `genero_id`. Ambas as colunas fazem parte da chave primária desta tabela.

Ah, observe que usei `Set`, não `List`. O motivo é que os gêneros de um alimento não têm ordem e nem repetição, vez que provavelmente não faz sentido dizer que o gênero A aparece antes do gênero B e nem que o gênero C pode aparecer duas ou três vezes. Caso você precise considerar a possibilidade de repetições ou de um ordenamento bem definido que não seja algo simples como a mesma ordem em que os elementos são declarados no `enum`, então recomendo que você crie uma entidade (`@Entity`) para modelar isso.

Ah, e como não faz sentido o `Set` conter o elemento `null`, então temos o `nullable = false` na anotação `@Column`.

No caso de você ter uma chave primária composta na tabela envolvente, você vai precisar usar um array de `@JoinColumn`s e deverá definir também o `referencedColumnName` em cada `@JoinColumn` para fazer o mapeamento corretamente.

---

**EXTRA**: No caso de você querer fazer algo parecido com uma `String` ou um `int` ao invés de um `enum`, o `@Enumerated` pode ser dispensado. Para fazer isso com campos de datas, use também o `@Temporal`. Se quiser um `@Embedded` no lugar do enum, use a anotação `@AttributeOverrides` para especificar como serão mapeados os campos do `@Embedded` (mas talvez aí já seja melhor definir uma nova entidade).

Comment: Funcionou aqui cara, muito obrigado!! Ótima resposta, além dar a solução explicou tudo direitinho. Vlw!!!